# Python: append images in for loop use a lot of memory

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

I'm actually facing a problem while working on a python project.
I'm appending some images in a for loop and it uses a lot of RAM memory.

If you guys, have any solution to optimize this for loop, It'll help me a lot.

Thanks!

````
augment_img = []
augment_label = []
augment_weight = []
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(len(train_dataset)):
        single_img, single_label, single_weight = train_dataset[j]
        augment_img.append(single_img)
        augment_label.append(single_label)
        augment_weight.append(single_weight)
        if j % 1000==0:
            print(j)```
````

Comment: It is really depending on what do you need to do with your lists, but have you consider hashing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of loading all images at once, I would suggest loading them in batches. There are different ways to handle that. In both `pytorch` and `tensorflow`, you can save your weights and continue training after some point. So, you can:

- iterate through your images in batches
- load the model weights and train the model
- save the weights for the next round

But easier way is to use default functions implemented in `pytorch` for example that does the same. For example using `ImageFolder` and `DataLoader`:

```py
def load_data(data_folder, batch_size, train, kwargs):
    transform = {
        'train': transforms.Compose(
            [transforms.Resize([256, 256]),
                transforms.RandomCrop(224),
                transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
                transforms.ToTensor(),
                transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                                  std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])]),
        'test': transforms.Compose(
            [transforms.Resize([224, 224]),
                transforms.ToTensor(),
                transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                                  std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])])
        }
    data = datasets.ImageFolder(root = data_folder, transform=transform['train' if train else 'test'])
    data_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(data, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, **kwargs, drop_last = True if train else False)
    return data_loader
```

You can specify the folder that contains images ending with various extensions (e.g. .jpg, .png. etc.) and then training your model by passing `data_loader` to.

Comment: Yes I totally agree that "batches" approach is the best regarding the data volume size.
Thanks aminrd :)